# Using Bash script to launch Python, store its PID and return success upon its completion

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal

i am trying to create a small job scheduler for submitting python job so I am using Bash to record its PID and create a while loop to test if the process has completed and return completed status after its indeed finished.

I created dummy python script called dummy_python.py:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print("hello world")
    time.sleep(2)
```

And the Bash to submit and record its PID and return success after its completing:

```
#! /bin/bash

job=`python dummy_python.py | ps aux | grep dummy_python.py | awk '{print $2}'`
echo "$job" 
echo "starting"
while true
do
sleep 1

top | grep $job > /dev/null

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]];then

        echo "job completed"
        break;

fi

done
```

So I am starting python code, taking its PID and storing in variable `job`  and then checking if the status of the job is completed by performing `top | grep ..` . The python job does get submittd but I get:

```
    Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

14025
14027
starting
grep: 14027: No such file or directory
job completed
```

dont see hello world being printed and I get to PIDs in the terminal after its completing. What is happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I'm guessing you might need quotes here: `grep $job` ...I think it probably runs the command instead of passing it as string to grep

Comment: [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: `top` is the wrong tool here; you simply test with `kill -0 "$pid" || echo "The process has finished"` or perhaps marginally with `ps`. There is `top -b` for noninteractive use, but there is still no guarantee that yours is among the top active processes.

Comment: Also, nothing is being run in the background here - by the time `job` gets a value, the Python process has already finished running.

Comment: Probably look up what `|` does; you are feeding the output from your Python job to the pipeline, and basically killing it when the final process in the pipe finds a match. This should probably simply be closed as a duplicate about how to run shell commands in the background (hint: `&`)

Comment: @tripleee so we cannot assign the PID of the python program and store it at the same time? i.e. the python program will finish running then its value gets assigned to the `job` variable?

Comment: There is no way to assign a variable in the background; the script can only proceed with a value in the variable once that value is available. It's hard to imagine which problem exactly you are hoping to solve or how you imagine the script to work if the variable's value isn't yet available at any point after the actual assignment statement. A simple way to defer the assignment is to do something like `job >file & pid=$!; : other code ...; wait "$pid"; value=$(cat file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am starting python code, taking its PID and storing in variable job and then checking if the status of the job is completed by performing `top | grep ..` .

That may be what you intend, but it's not what you're doing.

```
job=`python dummy_python.py | ps aux | grep dummy_python.py | awk '{print $2}'`
```

The command inside the backticks (`` characters) is a pipeline; it connects the output of one program to the input of the next.  Python's output goes to `ps aux` , `ps`'s output goes to `grep`, and `grep`'s output goes to `awk`.

Within backticks `...`, or alternately the more universal and preferred `$( ... )`, [is called command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands), and it means the command `...`  will be executed and its position in the script will be replaced by the *output* of the command `...`. This implies that the command must run to completion before the substitution can be made.

So what you're doing in that line is executing your python script, sending it's output to `ps aux`, sending `ps`'s output to `grep`, sending `grep`'s output to `awk`, and then, once the pipeline finishes executing, storing `awk`'s output in `job`.

`ps aux | grep dummy_python.py | awk '{print $2}'` is a logical construction; list processes, grep for the process matching the regex `dummy_python.py`, and then print the second column.  But ...

> dont see hello world being printed

`python dummy.py|ps aux` doesn't really make sense; [`ps` does not read from standard input](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) which is why python complains `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`; it's trying to write `hello world` to its standard output, which is connected to `ps`'s standard input, but `ps` doesn't read from the standard input.  When `ps` ends, the pipe is broken.

As described in the comments, `top` is good only for interactively monitoring  the most active processes on the computer.  `ps` is the correct choice when you want to  use the list of running processes in a script.

```
top | grep $job > /dev/null
```

Remember, `job` is the output of `ps aux | grep dummy_python.py | awk '{print $2}'`.  Even though your python script's output is discarded, otherwise that pipeline is correctly listing processes, filtering out the lines containing `dummy_python.py` and selecting it's Process ID.  so `$job` becomes the process ID of the python script, *when it was running*. Recall the script must end before the command substitution can be assigned to `job`.

> I get t[w]o PIDs in the terminal after its completing.

Becuase you're running 2 commands that contain the string `dummy_python.py`: `python dummy_python.py` and `grep dummy_python.py`.

```
top | grep $job > /dev/null
```

`$job` is replaced by `14025 14027`.  It is not in quotes so it becomes two arguments to grep.  If you look at [the way grep works in its `man` page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

> ```
>        grep [OPTION...] PATTERNS [FILE...]
> ```

`14025` is becoming the `PATTERNS` for which it searches, and `14027` is interpreted as `FILE`.  That's why you get

```
grep: 14027: No such file or directory
```

> how can it be fixed?

First, you should understand that shell scripting is not easy.  It's actually quite difficult to do correctly and there's many pitfalls.  `python` can do everything `bash` can do; stick to higher level languages if you don't want to learn shell.  If you want to script in `bash` you really must learn about how it works; its syntax is comparatively arcane and you *cannot* guess your way through it.

Unlike python, bash will not automatically abort the script on error; it will continue to execute even if commands end in an exit status.  You need to invoke `bash -e` or `set -e` if you want errors to result in script abortion.

> I get t[w]o PIDs in the terminal

Because the grep pattern matches itself.

The easiest solution for this particular problem is to make the `grep` command not match its own pattern; one way is to turn the pattern into an equivalent pattern that doesn't match itself (eg `[d]ummy_python.py` matches `dummy_python.py` but does *not* match itself.)

But you don't need to do any of the stuff you are doing in the script.  You need to:

1. run the script in the background
2. wait until the script completes
3. print `job completed`.

Bash has built-ins to do all of this stuff.  you don't need to search for the   PID; `$!` provides it.  You don't have to poll for the script to finish; bash built-in `wait` handles that more succinctly and efficiently.  You *do* need to run `python` in the background if you want the script to proceed before it ends; `&` instead of `;` or newline achieves that through bash's built-in job control.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
python -c 'from time import sleep; print ("hello world"); sleep(2); print("goodbye world")' &
job=$!
echo "job started, pid $job"
wait $job
echo "job completed"
```

Comment: Awsome explanation! Is there also a way to submit python job and simultaneously assign its PID to a variable like `job` above, or the best we can do here is use `$!`?  Also kudos for the minimal code

Comment: `job=$!` is what you want.  Keep in mind `$!` represents the pid of the last process you started, so save it to `job` right after invoking python, before you invoke anything else.  "submit" is a strange verb to use.  You're executing a process.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash


python dummy_python.py > dummy_python.log 2>&1 &
PID=$!
echo "stating with pid: $PID"

while kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null; do
 sleep 1
done

echo "job completed"
```

---

```
$ time ./tst.sh
stating with pid: 286701
job completed

real    0m20.050s
user    0m0.021s
sys     0m0.044s

$ cat dummy_python.log
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

Comment: This answer is essentially correct, but explains nothing.  I think the OP could use an explanation more than a working example.

Comment: This works well, perhaps little explanation would have been better.  +1 though.